# If I have two queries with the same field but different sort field then, should I create a single compound index or multiple compound index

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, indexing, mongodb-atlas

If I have two queries with the same field but different sort fields then, do I need to create a single compound index or multiple compound index with different sort fields?

I am working on an e-commerce site, where I want to query by category and sort by (date or price) based on user preference. How many single and compound indexes, will I need to create?

A user might make the following queries

- Query by Category and sort by date
- Query by Category and sort by price
- Query without Category and sort by date
- Query without Category and sort by price

The category here is an array of strings.

#### Option 1

```
post.index({
  category: 1,
  price: -1,
  cratedAt: -1,
});
```

#### Option 2

```
post.index({
  category: 1,
  price: -1,
});

post.index({
  category: 1,
  createdAt: -1,
});

post.index({
  createdAt: -1,
});

post.index({
  price: -1,
});
```

Which option is better?

I am using MongoDB, but I would also appreciate, how it can be done in other databases.

I am expecting millions of items. So, there needs to be least number of indexes because RAM is limited.

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing at least the queries, the amount of data in the tables and how the column values are distributed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "query by category" means exact equality on a single supplied value (not pattern matching, not `IN`-list or `=ANY`), then in PostgreSQL you would need 4 indexes for each query to be optimal:

```
(category, price)
(category, date)
(price)
(date)
```

If you want to key-set pagination, then you would need to include a tie-breaking column, presumably "id", on the end of each one.

Comment: What if "IN" was involved?

Comment: @CuriousFlower If it has `WHERE category IN ('a','b') order by price` then PostgreSQL would probably read all rows of those two categories and sort them, and any column in the index after the first one (on category) would go unused.  Other databases might be more clever here.  But if the IN list only contained one element, PostgreSQL would just treat it the same as a simple equality test.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL:

- `INDEX(Category, createdAt)` for Query by Category and sort by date
- `INDEX(Category, price)` for Query by Category and sort by price
- `INDEX(createdAt)` for Query without Category and sort by date
- `INDEX(price)` for Query without Category and sort by price

Don't worry about `ASC` or `DESC`.

That is, you need 4 different indexes.  (The Optimizer will be happy to pick from among them.)

"RAM is limited" -- This is not critical, because index blocks are cached.

Will the queries include `LIMIT`?  Any other items in `WHERE`?

Please show us `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, there may be some other improvements I can suggest.

(Please limit Questions to a single DB engine.)